# Reading the swagger.yaml file to get key and its value to the wso2 apim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

When importing an API from an API Archive to the wso2am, I want to get the value of the `host` key. Which file does this so i can use the `host` value.

Answer (score 2):

When uploading a swagger definition, it is getting validated by parsing the content of the yaml file. In your case (when uploading an archive file), the validation happens [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/definitions/OASParserUtil.java#L703).

Since you are referring to `swagger 2.0`, the host attribute is parsed and stored in this [Swagger](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/definitions/OASParserUtil.java#L748) object.

The host name can be retrieved using [`swagger.getHost()` method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-models/1.5.21/io/swagger/models/Swagger.html).

Comment: Hi thank you. I want to execute this in the `extractEndpointURLs` method in the `APIMappingUtil.java` class.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how i get the swagger definition in the extractEndpointURLs class so I can get the host from that?

Comment: API object is passed to this method - `extractEndpointURLs` and it has the swagger definition of API. You can introduce a new method to parse the swagger and retrieve hostname if there isn't a method already.

Comment: `                   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                    try {
                        JSONObject swagger = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(api.getSwaggerDefinition());
                        String host =  swagger.get("host").toString();
                        apiURLsDTO.setHttps(host);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }` i tried this but when debugging found out that the swagger definition value was null. for some reason swagger definition attribute was null.

Comment: There is a method named [getOpenAPIDefinition](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/AbstractAPIManager.java#L1212) in `AbstractAPIManager.java` to retrieve the swagger definition using `apiId`. You could use that.